# Community Promotion Ads - 2016

Tags: discussion, community-ads

It's 2016 now, and we've [made some changes to the sidebar size](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272563/were-standardizing-the-sidebar-width-at-300px-on-all-sites). As such, we can now restart the Community Promotion Ads for 2016!

Keep in mind, we have updated some of the guidelines compared to previously - the changes are marked in bold in the Image Requirements section.

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting unix and linux related open source apps
- the site's twitter account
- script packs or power tools
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be **300 x 250 pixels**, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of **150 KB**
- **If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px (2px if high DPI) border surrounding it.**

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/3854).

Comment: The limit on file size seems to be different from that [on Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14925/158442), where it's 150 KB.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Community Promotion Ads - 2017](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4337/community-promotion-ads-2017)

Answer (score 24):

[image: The universal operating system]

Comment: Debian GNU/Linux - A Universal Operating System +1

Answer (score 23):

[image: Greg's (GreyCat's) Bash Wiki]

Comment: Yes, please.  I think a majority of the questions tagged `bash` would be handled if people read that guide....

Comment: ...By the way, isn't [Pitfall 42](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf42) incorrect?  The third example there (the one marked "better still") does the *opposite* of the two examples preceding it.  (Is there somewhere I can propose a fix...?)

Comment: @Wildcard no, just confusing. The suggestion never specifies what the operation should do, it only illustrates how to pass file names correctly. Yes, the 1st two delete any files without a `.` in their name and the last one deletes any files _with_ a dot, but both are just examples. The point is that globs are the better way to pass file names. I guess you could edit and fix it if you like (you just need to create an account).

Comment: @Wildcard, the [change](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls?action=diff&rev1=413&rev2=414) was by [@ormaaj](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/7468/ormaaj) also active here. You can always ping him.

Answer (score 23):

[image: Vi and Vim Stack Exchange]

Comment: The corners seem off.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος Probably something went wrong when I tried to resize it. Unfortunately that's as far as my skills go, but if you can help, I got it originally from here: http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/a/1299/205 (Github link available)

Comment: No, I mean that the corners of the diamond shape in the middle seem to be *too off*.

Answer (score 21):

[image: raspberrypi.stackexchange.com]

Comment: RPi.SE needs more love.

Comment: @goldilocks - are you sure about the image size - I downloaded it and it came to 62.8 KBytes which seems to exceed the 40KBytes limit...?

Comment: @SlySven Thanks for that...grumble grumble I did use "max png compression" so I will have to figure something out.  Not really my wheelhouse.

Comment: Okay, done -- solution was to **posterize** to reduce the palette.

Comment: It's all that intricate PWB effect in the green background that is doing it, I bet.  But posterizing - which has side-effect of reducing the number of steps in any anti-aliasing - will help, as you have found... 8-P

Answer (score 18):

[image: Arch wiki]

Answer (score 14):

[image: Fedora distro news for users]

Answer (score 13):

[image: The Linux workstation you've been waiting for]

Answer (score 11):

[image: Fedora Cloud: Lean. Powerful. Everycloud ready.]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Fedora Server: The latest technology and a stable foundation for your apps and services.]

Answer (score 10):

[image: GNU Parallel - for people who live life in the parallel lane]

Answer (score 10):

[image: Create and run applications in Linux containers.]

Answer (score 7):

[image: Love software? Visit Software Recommendations]

Comment: Derived from [Undo's ad](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/856/133)

Answer (score 7):

[image: Unix-like operating system that is free software]

Comment: Long live the inverse [mouflon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mouflon#/media/File:Mouflon_in_zoo.jpg)!

Comment: "Tagline to show on mouseover."  Maybe that can be edited?  :)

Comment: @Wildcard just tried; you can suggest.

Answer (score 7):

[image: Why zsh is cooler than your shell]

Answer (score 5):

[image: GNU Parallel - for people who live life in the parallel lane]

Answer (score 4):

[image: Trisquel GNU/Linux]

Comment: A fully [Free](http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html), FSF [endorsed](http://www.gnu.org/distros/free-distros.html) GNU/Linux operating system!

Answer (score 2):

[image: Q & A on Emacs]

Answer (score 1):

[See all questions with active bounties http://stack-exchange-dynamic-ads.herokuapp.com/unix.stackexchange.com/bounty.png](https://unix.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured)

Comment: Copied from [Community Promotion Ads - 2015](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3408).

Answer (score -6):

[image: Follow us on Twitter]

Comment: This is a demonstration post to indicate how this should look when an ad is posted, now with 80px more width (to despise, as it were)! It also doubles as your twitter ad, but it's up to you if you wish to promote it by voting.